# How do i make an object emit an object that is emitting objects?

Tags: particles

How do i get an object to shoot out an object that is shooting out objects with the particle system.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.8 will have this feature, that will allow complex manipulation with particles (not only with particles):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQi2BqlQtnI

If you want to try something similar right now, you can try to use [Animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes), but you need to know, that it has not so good performance as particles.